# window.history.go not working

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I have a button on click of which I want to go one step back using javascript. for this I am using window.history.go although this works fine in IE7 and firefox it is not working in IE6 and there is no change as the user stays on the same page.

I m attaching the event to LinkButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE6 has trouble with window.history.go(). It works on regular links like this:

```
 <a href='#' onclick='history.go(-1);'>Back!</a>
```

But some others won't work. You could try this:

```
 <button onclick='history.go(-1);'>Back!</button>
```

But I'm not quite sure if that would work. You could also show a button for all other browsers and a link for IE:

```
 <button id='backButton' onclick='history.go(-1);'>Back!</button>
 <!--[if IE 6]>
 <script type='text/javascript'> document.getElementById('backButton').style.display = 'none'; </script>
 <a href='#' onclick='history.go(-1);'>Back!</a>
 <![endif]-->
```

It would offcourse be better to add the behaviout in a seperate javascript file instead of inline in the HTML. But I think you get the idea.

Comment: "history.back(); return false;" works brilliant thanx for your answere

Answer (score 0):

Use history.back()